# Reflection of transparent object is visible

Tags: mirror

I have an object in front of a mirror that i only make visible later in an animation.
Therefore, i made the object transparent, but the reflection of the object is still visible when i render it it. 
I use Blender Render.
The object is transparent but the reflection is visible. 
How do I make the reflection transparent as well?

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried animating the object's visibility/render property?

Answer (score 1):

Visibility settings in the Outliner (the little 'eye' and 'camera' icons) can be keyframed by pressing 'I' on them, so you can make your object appear at a certain frame of the animation.

Comment: Thanks but that wasnt my question

Comment: However i found a solution by setting the specular setting to 0